# "Missing keyword" in CASE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this `CASE` in the `where` clause but when I tried to save, the "missing keyword" error appears. The goal of this is to check if `a.term_date` is `null` then <strike>set</strike> add a condition that `:prm_date` is to be `not between b.date and c.date` and vice versa.

The code goes:

```
and ( 1 = CASE
          WHEN a.term_date is null then :prm_date between b.date and c.date
          ELSE :prm_date not between b.date and c.date 
          END )
```

I am not very sure if this is the best way to do this.

:prm_date is a date parameter that a user enters

Comment: What exactly do you mean "set :prm_date to be not between b.date and c.date"? What value would you want to be assigned to prm_date? Or is prm_date a true/false variable?

Comment: @Bohemian oh.. by "set" I mean is to add that as a condition if `a.term_date` is null and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
and (
    (a.term_date is null and :prm_date between b.date and c.date)
    or
    :prm_date not between b.date and c.date
)
```

Slightly excessive whitespace used to increase clarity.